# What are all the things that can contain the Holy Spirit?

Tags: biblical-basis, pneumatology

Based on biblical text, what are all the different kinds of "things" that can be filled/indwelt by the Holy Spirit?

The first and most obvious answer is a person, but also apparently a marriage:

> **Malachi 2:14-15 ESV** But you say, “Why does he not?” Because the Lord was witness between you and the wife of your youth, to whom you have been faithless, though she is your companion and your wife by covenant. Did he not make them one, **with a portion of the Spirit in their union**?

This got me thinking: what else can have the Spirit of God in them? A country? An animal? An inanimate object?

A good answer can provide a couple non-obvious things or a comprehensive list of all things. Please note that this is not a "*list/shopping question*" because I'm asking the answers to be sourced from a closed set of data→the bible.

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I do not know how there could be one accepted answer.

Comment: @TheFreemason More than one answer may be "correct", but I'll accept the answer that has the best solution to my problem per site guidelines: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Just thinking out loud:  I assert that only nouns could have the attribute of having the holy spirit.  That is, verbs and adverbs could not.  So then by definition, persons, places, things, and ideas are potential suspects.  We know that persons can be full of the holy spirit.  We know that ideas (marriage is an idea) can be full of the holy spirit.  So then, can places and things be full of the holy spirit?  I would suspect that a Catholic would say that the rosary can be full of the holy spirit.  Maybe someone can use this comment to build an answer.

Comment: I think "one accepted answer" could be acheived by having a list that's complete or mostly so.

Comment: @DonBranson Lists are usually concerning to have as answers as someone could say, "Oh, you forgot X" then the list is moot.

Comment: @TheFreemason I've seen them used effectively on SO without running into the problem you state. Answers are editable, so items can be added to the list later. Besides, the OP seems to be asking for a list.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is misleading.

> Did He not make them one, with a portion of the Spirit in their union?

this doesn't say that the marriage is filled with the Spirit, it says that He blessed the marriage by the Holy Spirit, with the Holy Spirit.

The Holy Spirit is a thing that takes action, It does things like filling, blessing, anointing, joining  etc.

The Spirit is not in the Marriage, the Spirit is among them in the Marriage.

---

The point I am trying to make is that really anything can be affected by the Holy Spirit.

Comment: This is a good observation against a single point I made but it doesn't really answer my original question.

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: "Affected" by the Spirit isn't what I asked either. Certainly God can affect whatever He wants, but I'm asking what has scripture stated can be filled or indwelt by the Holy Spirit.

Comment: Scripture states that the Holy Spirit is a person, a thing that takes action.  it can dwell only where it is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question.  I have read the verse in many different english Bible translations and found that many do not make the same statement. Some don't even reference the Spirit at all (in assumption that this is not the point of the message being conveyed in the verse) but some do make this reference but mostly indicating to "..containing a residue of the spirit in them..".

The indication of the Spirit in this verse is unique and being offered only as an *explanation* to the two people becoming **ONE BEING** in marriage.  It can only be done because the two people, having been born again, both contain their portion of the Spirit within them and therefore sealed as **ONE BEING** in the consummation of marriage which can only be done by the Holy Spirit.

**Only people can contain the Spirit (Holy Spirit) of God:**

> John 14:16(ESV)"And I will ask the Father, and he will give you another Helper, to be with you forever,"
>
> John 14:26(ESV)"But the Helper, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, he will teach you all things and bring to your remembrance all that I have said to you."
>
> Romans 5:5(ESV) "and hope does not put us to shame, because God's love has been poured into our hearts through the Holy Spirit who has been given to us.

---

Now, if by asking "if A country? An animal? An inanimate object?" can also have the Spirit of God in them you are wanting to know if such things can *carry* a special blessing in them because they may "*have*" the Spirit in them... then that would become a topic of BLESSINGS & CURSES which the Bible speaks much of and so then, YES, things, places and animals can "*have*" in them a blessing or a curse.

> Leviticus 27:28(ESV) “But no devoted thing that a man devotes to the Lord, of anything that he has, whether man or beast, or of his inherited field, shall be sold or redeemed; every devoted thing is most holy to the Lord.
>
> Deuteronomy 30:19(ESV) "I call heaven and earth to witness against you today, that I have set before you life and death, blessing and curse. Therefore choose life, that you and your offspring may live,"
>
> Proverbs 3:33(ESV) “The curse of the Lord is on the house of the wicked, but He blesses the dwelling of the righteous."
>
> Luke 9:16(KJV) "Then he took the five loaves and the two fishes, and looking up to heaven, he blessed them, and brake, and gave to the disciples to set before the multitude.
>
> 1 Corinthians 10:16(ESV) "The cup of blessing that we bless, is it not a participation in the blood of Christ? The bread that we break, is it not a participation in the body of Christ?
>
> Deuteronomy 7:27(ESV) "And you shall not bring an abominable thing into your house and become devoted to destruction like it. You shall utterly detest and abhor it, for it is devoted to destruction."
>
> Deuteronomy 13:16-17(ESV) "You shall gather all its spoil into the midst of its open square and burn the city and all its spoil with fire, as a whole burnt offering to the LORD your God. It shall be a heap forever. It shall not be built again." (KJV)"And there shall cleave none of the accursed thing to your hand: that the LORD may turn from the fierceness of his anger, and show you mercy, and have compassion upon you, and multiply you, as he has sworn unto your fathers;"

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

First I noticed from the scripture that the Holy Spirit is a Him, a person. Jesus told us that unless He Jesus went away, the Holy Spirit would not come to us, and Jesus called Him, 'The Comforter'. This is a title of the Holy Spirit. John 16.

A characteristic of the Holy Spirit is that 'He doesn't speak of Himself, but draws attention to Jesus and lifts Jesus up.'

> John 16 King James Version (KJV)
>   16 These things have I spoken unto you, that ye should not be offended.
>   2 They shall put you out of the synagogues: yea, the time cometh, that whosoever killeth you will think that he doeth God service.
>   3 And these things ***will they do unto you, because they have not known the Father, nor me.***

4 But these things have I told you, that when the time shall come, ye may remember that I told you of them. And these things I said not unto you at the beginning, because I was with you.
5 But now I go my way to him that sent me; and none of you asketh me, Whither goest thou?
6 But because I have said these things unto you, sorrow hath filled your heart.
7 Nevertheless I tell you the truth; It is expedient for you that I go away: ***for if I go not away, the Comforter will not come unto you; but if I depart, I will send him unto you.***

8 And when he is come, ***he will reprove the world of sin, and of righteousness, and of judgment:***

9 **Of sin, because they believe not on me;**

10 **Of righteousness**, because I go to my Father, and ye see me no more;

11 **Of judgment, because the prince of this world is judged.**

12 I have yet many things to say unto you, but ye cannot bear them now.
13 Howbeit when ***he***(a person), the Spirit of truth, is come, ***he(a person)*** will ***guide you into all truth:*** for he shall *not speak of himself*; but ***whatsoever he shall hear, that shall he speak: and he will shew you things to come***.

14 He shall ***glorify me***: for he shall receive of mine, and shall shew it unto you.
15 All things that the Father hath are mine: therefore said I, that he shall take of mine, and shall shew it unto you.

The Holy Spirit can indwell people, and by this method He is the third party in a marriage where both people have Him inside them. (Christians)

The Holy Spirit is called The Comforter, with the idea of being all to us that would cause us to feel comforted and secure, picture ie. The Comforter on a bed, it warms you, it's soft, kind to the body and skin. The Holy Spirit would be this way to us, kind, and soft, warming and comforting.

The Holy Spirit may become a part of tangible objects, because we see from scripture the Holy Spirit acted upon the waters at creation, upon Mary's egg at Jesus' conception, ...somehow He mixed with oil during annointing, and His Presence may somehow act upon and change cloth, or other objects for His purposes, even animals may be acted upon in intrinsic ways producing unusual results, ie. the donkey in the Old Testament who could identify an invisible angel, and after that spoke a sentence of words.